# How to check the equality of two decimals with an acceptable error margin

Tags: c#, .net, math, decimal

I have two decimals:

```
var first = 1.567m;
var second = 1.568m;
var areEqual = first == second; // false
```

And I have an acceptable margin of error; which is `0.010`.
So what I need is a Check method:

```
Check(first: 1.567m, second: 1.577m, margin: 0.010m); // true
Check(first: 1.567m, second: 1.578m, margin: 0.010m); // false
Check(first: 1.567m, second: 1.578m, margin: 0.011m); // true
```

How can I write that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if (Math.Abs(first - second) <= margin)
```

Comment: `public static bool Check(decimal first, decimal second, decimal margin) { return Math.Abs(first - second) <= margin; }`